# Active Model Serializers 0.10 exclude namespaces with JSON adapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

Is there some way to exclude the namespace part of the model name in the root key?

I used Active Model Serializer version 0.9 before and my JSON representation of a `User` at localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1 was something like:

```
{ "user": { "id": 1, "first_name": "Foo", "last_name": "Bar" } }
```

I recently upgraded to version 0.10 and now I get the namespace included in the root key:

```
{ "api/v1/user": { "id": 1,"first_name": "Foo", "last_name": "Bar" } }
```

I want the root key to be like before, that is "user" instead of "api/v1/user".

### Edit 1

I am using the `:json` adapter.

### Edit 2

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1756) at the repository on GitHub. Let's see what they say about it.

### Edit 3

The [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md#json) for Active Model Serializers have been updated. It explains how to override the root key.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using the JSON adapter and from looking at the code you have a couple of options:

1. Specify the `root` during rendering of your resource as

   ```
   render json: @user, root: "user"
   ```
2. It seems like the root is fetched by calling the serializer's `json_key` method so if you override that method you should be able to define the root at the serializer level.
3. You may be able to override initialize on your serializer to call `super` with adding the root option since it's assigned on initialize of the Serializer base class https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/b4e2ac300cdb4424549660a175c8cb777194b065/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L109

Comment: Alternative 1 is suitable if you want to manipulate some specific rendering, but since I use namespaces for all my models in my API, this is not a great option for me.

Comment: Those are the only options I can find while browsing the current code/documentation